# Why the model value is wrong with checkbox in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am experiencing a really strange error. I have a checkbox in my view whose has a directive to show the value of it when it changes. In FF it works well showing the right values. But in other browsers, like Chrome, it shows the the opposite response, i.e., if is checked, should show 'true', but shows 'false'!

In my view:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="accept" name="accept" ng-model="accept" d6 />
```

My directive:

```
validation.directive('d6', ['$parse', function($parse){
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link:  function link(scope, elem, attrs, control) {

         elem.on('change', function(){

             console.log(control.$modelValue);

         });

      }
 }
}]);
```

[image]

Comment: Can you supply a JS Fiddle or some more code so we don't have to rewrite everything from scratch.

Comment: Here is: http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/306/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular way of doing this would be using `$watch`:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('d6', function(){
   return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      link:  function link(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {               
          scope.$watch(
              function () {
                  return ngModel.$modelValue;
              }, function(newValue) {
                  console.log(newValue);
              }
          );

      }
   }
});
```

There is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd3FT/2/).

Answer (score 2):

**Angular code**

Found in the angular code in the `checkboxInputType` function used for all input[type=checkbox] with a `ngModelController`:

```
element.on('click', function() {
    scope.$apply(function() {
        ctrl.$setViewValue(element[0].checked);
    });
});
```

This code updates the `ngModelController` with the boolean as view value, instantly piped into provided parsers, thus setting the model value.

**Click and change events**

You are listening to the `change` event, which is triggered before the `click` event in Chrome and the opposite in firefox. That is the whole problem.

**Solutions**

The jQuery solution is to listen to the `click` event too.

The Angular solution would be to watch the model value directly.

Answer (score 1):

Either what the two answers said, or you can simply watch for the changes in $scope.accept (which is your model):

```
$scope.$watch('accept', function(){
    $scope.value = $scope.accept; 
});
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/A8Vgk/307/. This way seems the most natural to me.

Comment: The only drawback of this approach is that directive is usable only when scope variable name is `accept`.